# How to pass a paramater multiple times through React-Navigation in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, react-navigation

```
function A() {
  const [levels, setLevels] = React.useState(null);

  // upon the component mount, we call the database.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    database()
      .ref()
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
        //get Levels from db
        const levels = snapshot.map((child) => child.key);
        setLevels(levels);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
          <View>
            {levels.map((element) => {
              return <B level={element} />;
            })}
          </View>
  );
}
```

```
function B(props){    
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    return (
        <View>

        <TestButton
            title={props.level}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('C')}
        />

        </View>
    );
}
```

I currently am already passing the value 'level' to the TestFunc parameter, but now I wish to pass the same parameter to the screen I navigate to when I press the TestButton component.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

This documentation shows me how I would do such with a newly initialized parameter, but it doesn't seem to work with parameters that have been passed from previous screens.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I have tried to make it a little bit clearer. I want to go from function A to B to C, all different components/screens in my app. I want to take the 'level' that I obtain from function A and pass it from B to C. Currently I am correctly retrieving the 'level' value in function B, however I can not seem to pass it to function C.

Comment: How you passed the parameter can you please saw ?

Comment: you want send param(s) from screen A to screen  B or screen B to screen A ??

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function TestFunc (props){    
const navigation = useNavigation();
return (
    <View>

    <TestButton
        title={props.level}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Category',{...props})}
       //{...props} send all props that's exist in props argument 
    />

    </View>
  );
}
```

You can get the all props on Category component also

```
const { level } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
```

Comment: I get Component Exception: undefined is not an object, when evaluating 'this.props' when retrieving the props in the Category component. I get the same error if I try just props.params.

Comment: Nevermind, changing it from 'props' to 'route' in the Category component and retrieving it via const {level} = route.params; solved my issue. Thanks!